# PhoneGap external URL content

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing an iphone app with PhoneGap and JQM and I need to be able to access data on my server (http://xxxxx.com/xx.php) it is just simple plain data and need to able to replace the current div with that of the content , I tried JQM and JQ but it didn't work although I whitelisted my server , any idea ?

Comment: Did you give your app permission to use the internet? http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/AndroidManifest.html

Comment: Have you enabled crossdomain in your phonegap.xml file (android) or PhoneGap.plist file (ios) and have you enabled crossdomain in jquerymobile too?

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding * as a wildcard to the ExternalHosts within the PhoneGap.plist. Although if you have added your sever as you say, this should work.

Do you get any errors within the logs? I would also suggest doing a clean before a build too.